# Qt two QList member variables causes crash

Tags: c++, qt, memory, crash, heap-memory

so I'm not sure if this is a bug in Qt or if I just don't understand something, but i have this class:

```
class myClass : public QDialog, private Ui::myClass
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit myClass(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QList<ushort> list1;
    QList<ushort> list2;
}
```

I create this window by clicking on an action in another window:

```
void mainWindow::on_myClassAction_triggered()
{
    myClass *mc = new mc(NULL);
    mc->show();
}
```

So now things get weird. Even if i don't use list1 and list2 anywhere in myClass, the program will crash when i close or sometimes open myClass. If i comment out one, or both of them, it works. What is going on here??

Comment: To be honest i dont think it has something to do with QList.. i would suggest you post some more code

Comment: That's all the code I have to post! In the second block, if i change `myClass *mc = new mc(NULL)` with `myClass *mc = new mc(this)` then things work. I beliebe it has something to do with the deletion of the QList, because the error thrown on the crash is `HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED`

Comment: Well i would suggest then to trace constructor..

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with that terminology. What do you mean to trace constructor?

Comment: Re-ran qmake and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Qt Creator. I just re-ran QMake and now it works. Definitely was some sort of bug within Qt/Qt Creator.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug of any sort. It's a classic binary incompatibility problem: you've had some code that depended on the layout of some of your classes, but the outdated Makefiles did not capture that dependency. Thus when you changed the layout of the class, the dependent code didn't get recompiled. It would be way too expensive for `qmake` to rescan the entire project looking for such dependencies every time you build it. It's on you to re-run `qmake` when you change the code to introduce such binary incompatibilities.

For small projects, you may simply wish to *always* rebuild the code, forcing a qmake re-run.

Comment: I agree with you that there is indeed the problem that you described (I am facing it myself almost every day and doing exactly what you suggest here) but I am still wondering how Visual Studio (or msbuild) manages to to instantly catch all dependencies and correctly build very large projects in the same situations. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It does so because it doesn't use qmake. Qmake isn't really a tool designed for incremental use. Cmake would be a better choice. qbs is probably the best choice: it doesn't suffer from such problems.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'll try to learn this subject better (I need to design a custom automated build system and I hope this will help).